# Custom UUID's as primary keys

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, guid, uuid

I noticed that Slack uses ID's of the form `U023BECGF`, and not the standard `f3a7a018-02da-4cdb-944c-44d073536648` you often see

What is the reasoning for this?

Comment: What does this have to do with Postgres? And the answer is probably: because it's shorter...!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you put in your question (`U023BECGF`) is not a valid or complete UUID.  UUIDs are 16 bytes (octets) which are represented as 32 characters of hexadcimal as standard: RFC: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt 
Under no encoding is `U023BECGF` a representation of a 16 bytes; it's too short.

It is plausable that these keys could be incorperated into a UUID but they are not one in themselvs.

The usual reason for smaller fields is storing less data.